# Resizing nested tree elements on hover

Tags: jquery, css, resize, jquery-animate

I've got problem with resising event on hover. I use nested tree(screen in link)

http://imgur.com/yONfFf4

When i hover on '3' or '2' I want to shrink current tree node and enlarge hovering element to show some information about others tree node elements. I am working on angular and using directive for that. Here is part of my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               $timeout(function(){
                   var treeNode = element[0].previousElementSibling;
                   var treeNodeWidth = element[0].previousElementSibling.offsetWidth;
                   $(treeNode).outerWidth(treeNodeWidth - element[0].offsetWidth - 5);

                   var elementChildrenWidth = element.children().width();
                   prevTreeNode = $(element).prev();
                   prevTreeNodeWidth = $(prevTreeNode).width();
                   resizeWidth = prevTreeNodeWidth - 100;

// =====> This is part with my issue 
                   $(element).children().hover(function() {
                        $(this).animate({width: '100px'}, 2000);
                        $(prevTreeNode).animate({width: resizeWidth}, 2000);
                   }, function() {
                        $(this).animate({width: '20px'}, 500);
                        $(prevTreeNode).animate({width: prevTreeNodeWidth}, 500);
                   });

               });
           });
```

Html structure is simple:

```
<ul class="shortLangContainer" ng-if="node.pagesMerged" set-tree-node-width>
                    <li ng-repeat="shortLang in node.pagesMerged">{{shortLang.langId}} <div class="shortLangContent">{{shortLang.menuPos}}</div></li>
                </ul>
```

I tried to use setTimeout, delay tanstitions, add class but animation is still messy. Maybe it is the way to make it works properly. It is possible to trigger another hover event only when the first end?

EDIT: Here is whole directive:

```
app.directive('setTreeNodeWidth', function($timeout) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               $timeout(function(){
                   var treeNode = element[0].previousElementSibling;
                   var treeNodeWidth = element[0].previousElementSibling.offsetWidth;
                   $(treeNode).outerWidth(treeNodeWidth - element[0].offsetWidth - 5);

                   var elementChildrenWidth = element.children().width();
                   prevTreeNode = $(element).prev();
                   prevTreeNodeWidth = $(prevTreeNode).width();
                   resizeWidth = prevTreeNodeWidth - 100;

                   $(element).children().hover(function() {
                        $(this).animate({width: '100px'}, 2000);
                        $(prevTreeNode).animate({width: resizeWidth}, 2000);
                   }, function() {
                        $(this).animate({width: '20px'}, 500);
                        $(prevTreeNode).animate({width: prevTreeNodeWidth}, 500);
                   });

               });
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS and jQuery together?

Comment: Yes, I am using it together. It is bad idea? I am a newbie in angular. I think my problem is with bad function in jQuery. I can't synchronize events.

Comment: Yes, in general you want to avoid using jQuery while using angular. It's purely guidelines though, not law :-) If you're going to be using any jQuery scripts, for example for manipulating the DOM, I recommend you do it in a directive.

Comment: Thank you, in fact i am using directive for that. I'll add whole code to my post.

Comment: jQuery function is working very messy, becouse the all elements resizing and sometimes events repeats many times. I don't know how to prevent this actions.